# Verb Plurality Agreement

Tags: grammatical-number

> The poem's colorful images give the reader pleasure.

Is the use of *give* here correct, or should *gives* be used?

Comment: You can consider *images* as the subject, so *give* is correct. Standard punctuation would indicate whether you mean one poem (*poem's*) or more than one (*poems'*). See [the answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55858/6951)

Answer (score 4):

"Give" is correct. Also note you're missing an apostrophe to indicate that the colorful images belong to the poem (or poems).

The poem's colorful images give the reader pleasure.
*(Many images from one poem give pleasure)*

The poems' colorful images give the reader pleasure.
*(Many images from many poems give pleasure)*

The poem's colorful image gives the reader pleasure
*(One image from one poem gives pleasure)*

The poems' colorful image gives the reader pleasure.
*(One composite image from many poems give pleasure)*